# Inherited method with return type of the class it's inside

Tags: c#, inheritance

Is there something I can put in the `/*???*/` (and anywhere else in `firstclass`) to make it return the type of the class that calls it, without overriding it in every class that inherits the method and without prefixing it with `(secondclass)` with every usage. Something that basically means `this.GetType()`?

```
public class firstclass
{
    private static /*???*/ current;
    public static /*???*/ modifycurrent()
    {
        /*do stuff to current*/
        return current;
    }
}
public class secondclass : firstclass
{
    //nothing concerning the above
}

//usage
secondclass a = new secondclass();
secondclass b = a.modifycurrent(); //<--no cast here
```

The goal is for every instance of `secondclass` to share a variable of the type `secondclass`. And when I make a third, fourth and fifth class that inherit from `firstclass` I don't have to rewrite all of these methods (that are exact mirrors of what's in `firstclass` except that the return type of `modifycurrent()` is different). An example of this is every type of form keeps track of the previously opened instance of itself.

Comment: modifycurrent is static so you cant invoke it through class instance...anyway what you ask is weird, can you explain what do you want to achieve?

Comment: a and b are secondclass? there is no casting at all, I can't understand what you're trying to achieve... maybe b should be firstclass?

Comment: When you find yourself trying to solve this sort of problem, it's usually best to step back and try to write the code differently instead of solving the original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use the Curiously Recurring Template pattern:

```
public class firstclass<T> where T:firstclass
{
    private T current;
    public T modifycurrent()
    {
        /*do stuff to current*/
        return current;
    }
}
public class secondclass : firstclass<secondclass>
{
    //nothing concerning the above
}
```

Note that I took off `static` since static members aren't inherited.

It's not *completely* fool-proof as you can do:

```
public class thirdclass : firstclass<secondclass>
{
    //nothing concerning the above
}
```

and `current` will still return an instance of `secondclass`.  There is no mechanism that forces inheritors to use its own type as the generic parameter.

Comment: This is good, but it needs to be static, because it's a way for the newly created `secondclass` to have information about the previously created static class.

Comment: Then no, because static members aren't inherited. You _could_ make the methods generic but without knowing what's in those methods I can't say whether that's a viable option or not.